# How can I unpack sequence?

Tags: python, expression

Why can't I do this:

```
d = [x for x in range(7)] 
a, b, c, d, e, f, g = *d
```

Where is it possible to unpack?
Only between parentheses of a function?

Answer (score 4):

You're using [`Extended Iterable Unpacking`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/) in wrong way.

```
d = [x for x in range(7)]  
a, b, c, d, e, f, g = d
print(a, b, c, d, e, f, g)
```

> Where it's possible to unpack? Only between parentheses of a function?

No,

`*` proposes a change to iterable unpacking syntax, allowing to specify a "catch-all" name which will be assigned a list of all items not assigned to a "regular" name.

You can try something like this:

```
a, *params = d
print(params)
```

Output

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Usually `*` (**Extended Iterable Unpacking**) operator is used when you need to pass parameters to a function.

**Note**

Javascript equivalent of **Extended Iterable Unpacking** `operator` is called [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

```js
d = [...Array(7).keys()]
console.log(d)

var [a, ...b] = d
console.log(a,b)
```

Comment: So why this is correct: t = 1, *rest, but this not: t =  *rest? The first one always automatically creates tuple?

Comment: t will hold the value for first element of `d` and rest of the values will be packed to `rest` variable.

Comment: The packed process will be produce in the left side of assignment.

Comment: but after printing 't' I receive all values not only the first one: (1, 2, 3), rest = [2, 3]
t = 1, *rest
print(t)

Answer (score 2):

You can also use this:

```
>>> a,b,c,d,e,f,g = range(7)
>>> a
0
>>> b
1
>>> c
2
```

Comment: sorry my bad, the range should be (7). this one will work: 
a,b,c,d,e,f,g = range(7)

Comment: I'll take care of that, thanks for the guideline @PM2Ring

Answer (score 1):

You don't appear to need the `*`

```
>>> z = [x for x in range(7)]
>>> a,b,c,d,e,f,g = z
>>> a
0
>>> b
1
>>> c
2
>>>
```

(I've used z rather than d twice.)

Comment: Yeah, you're right, I didn't notice this double 'd'.

Comment: NP. The double 'd' isn't why unpacking fails. Also you don't actually need the auxiliary variable either: `a,b,c,d,e,f,g = range(7)` works because unpacking works on iterables.

Comment: Yeah, I see but double use of same identifier is not a good practice.