# how do i write this code (easy way), python problem?

Tags: python-3.x

I am very new in Python, and I am really surprised at the following line of code.

```
p, q = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
```

how to write basic??

Comment: Something like `parts = input().split(); p = int(parts[0]); q = int(parts[1])`, maybe, but it's unclear what part of that is surprising to you - the multiple assignment (`foo, bar = baz`), the list comprehension (`[foo for foo in bar]`), something else?

Comment: tnx i got it  :)))

Comment: It uses [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and [sequence unpacking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50131152/how-can-i-unpack-sequence).

Answer (score 0):

You can make a loop instead to understand better, but the code won't work because the logic is false:

```
your_input = input().split() 
list_ = []
for x in your_input:
    list_.append(int(x))
p, q = list_
```

The `.split()` put the `str` in input in a list so you just have one element and one loop. But the `p,q =` at the end suggests it waits two elements in the list. So it can't work. Maybe you can delete the `.split()` if you want each digit of a number less than 100. Depends on the result you want.